# Error while uploading an image in a page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to quick edit my page and it gets me into an error statement which happens while replacing an existing image.. (image attached):

> Notice: Undefined index: field_benefits_collection in field_collection_field_attach_form() (line 1434 of /home/webmaster/parz/neosun2/web/wordpress2/drupal/v2/sites/all/modules/field_collection/field_collection.module).

Comment: Can you please post some code like what and how you were doing.?

Answer (score 0):

This is no error, it's only notice. You can ignore it or disable it in administration (http://step4wd.com/2013/09/26/turn-off-warning-error-messages-in-drupal/) or in php.ini (https://drupal.org/node/303492).